# How do I make a function that usually runs after an entry update the previous ones?

Tags: postgresql, concurrency, triggers, sql-update

Like the title says, I have a function that runs after every entry into the database. The problem is it's not affecting all the entries that have been entered before the trigger.

How can I make it update the previous ones?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION xll_transactions_gl_associated_objects_func(transaction_id bigint)
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
DECLARE    
   l_transaction transactions%rowtype;
BEGIN

   SELECT INTO l_transaction * FROM transactions WHERE transactions.id = transaction_id;   

   IF (l_transaction.load_id IS NOT NULL) THEN      
      UPDATE transactions SET associated_business_partner_id = (SELECT business_partner_id FROM loads WHERE  loads.id  = l_transaction.load_id) WHERE id = transaction_id;
      UPDATE transactions SET associated_invoice_no = coalesce(CAST((SELECT invoice_no FROM loads WHERE loads.id  = l_transaction.load_id) AS TEXT), '') WHERE id = transaction_id;
   END IF;

   IF (l_transaction.load_driver_contractor_credit_id IS NOT NULL) THEN      
      UPDATE transactions SET associated_truck_id = (SELECT truck_id FROM load_driver_contractor_credits WHERE  load_driver_contractor_credits.id  = l_transaction.load_driver_contractor_credit_id) WHERE id = transaction_id;
      UPDATE transactions SET associated_driver_id = (SELECT driver_id FROM load_driver_contractor_credits WHERE  load_driver_contractor_credits.id  = l_transaction.load_driver_contractor_credit_id) WHERE id = transaction_id;
   END IF;

   IF (l_transaction.load_driver_contractor_deduction_id IS NOT NULL) THEN      
      UPDATE transactions SET associated_truck_id = (SELECT truck_id FROM load_driver_contractor_deductions WHERE  load_driver_contractor_deductions.id  = l_transaction.load_driver_contractor_deduction_id) WHERE id = transaction_id;
      UPDATE transactions SET associated_driver_id = (SELECT driver_id FROM load_driver_contractor_deductions WHERE  load_driver_contractor_deductions.id  = l_transaction.load_driver_contractor_deduction_id) WHERE id = transaction_id;
   END IF;

   IF (l_transaction.load_payable_id IS NOT NULL) THEN      
      UPDATE transactions SET associated_truck_id = (SELECT truck_id FROM load_payables WHERE  load_payables.id  = l_transaction.load_payable_id) WHERE id = transaction_id;
      UPDATE transactions SET associated_driver_id = (SELECT driver_id FROM load_payables WHERE  load_payables.id  = l_transaction.load_payable_id) WHERE id = transaction_id;
   END IF;

   IF (l_transaction.load_payment_id IS NOT NULL) THEN      
      UPDATE transactions SET associated_business_partner_id = (SELECT business_partner_id FROM loads LEFT JOIN load_payments ON load_payments.load_id = loads.id WHERE  load_payments.id  = l_transaction.load_payment_id) WHERE id = transaction_id;
      UPDATE transactions SET associated_invoice_no = coalesce(CAST((SELECT invoice_no FROM loads LEFT JOIN load_payments ON load_payments.load_id = loads.id WHERE  load_payments.id  = l_transaction.load_payment_id)AS TEXT), '') WHERE id = transaction_id;
      UPDATE transactions SET associated_check_no = (SELECT check_no FROM load_payments  WHERE  load_payments.id  = l_transaction.load_payment_id) WHERE id = transaction_id;
   END IF;

   IF (l_transaction.payment_id IS NOT NULL) THEN      
      UPDATE transactions SET associated_business_partner_id = (SELECT business_partner_id FROM payments WHERE  payments.id  = l_transaction.payment_id) WHERE id = transaction_id;
      UPDATE transactions SET associated_invoice_no = (SELECT invoice_no FROM payments WHERE payments.id  = l_transaction.payment_id) WHERE id = transaction_id;
   END IF;

   IF (l_transaction.payment_item_id IS NOT NULL) THEN   
      UPDATE transactions SET associated_business_partner_id = (SELECT business_partner_id FROM payments WHERE  payments.id  = (SELECT bill_id FROM payment_items WHERE payment_items.id = l_transaction.payment_item_id)) WHERE id = transaction_id;
      UPDATE transactions SET associated_invoice_no = (SELECT invoice_no FROM payments WHERE payments.id  = (SELECT bill_id FROM payment_items WHERE payment_items.id = l_transaction.payment_item_id)) WHERE id = transaction_id;
      UPDATE transactions SET associated_check_no = (SELECT check_no FROM payment_details  WHERE  payment_details.id  = (SELECT payment_detail_id FROM payment_items WHERE payment_items.id = l_transaction.payment_item_id)) WHERE id = transaction_id;
   END IF;

   IF (l_transaction.statement_id IS NOT NULL) THEN
      UPDATE transactions SET associated_truck_id = (SELECT truck_id FROM statements WHERE statements.id  = l_transaction.statement_id) WHERE id = transaction_id;
      UPDATE transactions SET associated_driver_id = (SELECT driver_id FROM statements WHERE statements.id  = l_transaction.statement_id) WHERE id = transaction_id;
      UPDATE transactions SET associated_check_no = (SELECT check_no FROM statements  WHERE  statements.id  = l_transaction.statement_id) WHERE id = transaction_id;
   END IF;

   IF (l_transaction.statement_fuel_id IS NOT NULL) THEN
      UPDATE transactions SET associated_truck_id = (SELECT truck_id FROM statement_fuel WHERE statement_fuel.id  = l_transaction.statement_fuel_id) WHERE id = transaction_id;
      UPDATE transactions SET associated_driver_id = (SELECT driver_id FROM statement_fuel WHERE statement_fuel.id  = l_transaction.statement_fuel_id) WHERE id = transaction_id;
      UPDATE transactions SET associated_check_no = (SELECT check_no FROM statements  WHERE  statements.id  = l_transaction.statement_id) WHERE id = transaction_id;
   END IF;

   IF (l_transaction.work_order_id IS NOT NULL) THEN
      UPDATE transactions SET associated_business_partner_id = (SELECT customer_id FROM work_orders WHERE work_orders.id  = l_transaction.work_order_id) WHERE id = transaction_id;
      UPDATE transactions SET associated_invoice_no = CAST((SELECT work_order_no FROM work_orders  WHERE  work_orders.id  = l_transaction.work_order_id) AS TEXT) WHERE id = transaction_id;
      UPDATE transactions SET associated_check_no = (SELECT check_no FROM work_orders  WHERE  work_orders.id  = l_transaction.work_order_id) WHERE id = transaction_id;      
   END IF;

END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

Comment: Define "previous". Exactly. In a multi-user environment, that's not as obvious as you seem to think. There can be multiple transactions open in parallel. Each one only sees what's already committed. So there can be earlier timestamps or lower serial numbers from a sequence that still appear "later" in a table ...

Comment: Sorry about that. Basically, there is a table transactions with these "associated" columns (it has other but the function refers to these only). The function is triggered to work every time there's a new entry in the table and so far it works. But, only for the new entries.

I want to edit it somehow so I can run it once and update these columns for all the transactions that have been added before the function was implemented.

Comment: Update all including or excluding the actual row triggering the function? And I assume you want to prevent infinite loops ...

Comment: Excluding, I think. Yeah, no infinite loops please. I would appreciate a push in the right direction, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Optimizing that function is only possible with intimate knowledge of table definitions and the exact intention. primary and unique constraints, NOT NULL definitions and foreign keys are crucial.

For instance, you have multiple updates on the same column `associated_truck_id`. The outcome of that depends on the details of your constraints and foreign keys.

Since this is based on a trigger, you can make the function itself a trigger function, thereby simplifying the logic.

Finally, I have to state, that the whole workflow seems highly dubious. I cannot imagine a sane database model, where I would update all existing rows on the entry of a new row. Most probably you should re-consider your design.

Either way, you should **not** be running 25 (!) separate updates. That writes 25 new row versions and is very slow. In addition, the table gets bloated with many dead rows and vacuum has a lot of additional work to do. Everything can be done in a **single update**.

So, as proof of concept, here's how to convert this to single update.
For lack of information, assuming all references are foreign key columns and result in a single match.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trg_transactions_ins_aft()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$func$
BEGIN

UPDATE transactions t
SET    associated_business_partner_id = COALESCE(p2.business_partner_id, p1.business_partner_id, l2.business_partner_id, l1.business_partner_id, t.associated_business_partner_id)
     , associated_invoice_no          = COALESCE(p2.invoice_no, p1.invoice_no
                                                ,CASE WHEN n.load_payment_id IS NOT NULL THEN COALESCE(l2.invoice_no::text, '') -- simple COALESCE not possible here
                                                      WHEN n.load_id         IS NOT NULL THEN COALESCE(l1.invoice_no::text, '')
                                                      ELSE t.associated_invoice_no
                                                 END)
     , associated_truck_id            = COALESCE(st.truck_id,  lp.ruck_id,   ld.truck_id,  t.associated_truck_id)
     , associated_driver_id           = COALESCE(st.driver_id, lp.driver_id, ld.driver_id, t.associated_driver_id)
     , associated_check_no            = COALESCE(st.check_no,  pd.check_no,  lm.check_no,  t.associated_check_no)
FROM   NEW n
LEFT   JOIN loads                          l1 ON l1.id = n.load_id   -- if NEW.load_id IS NULL, we all NULLs here
LEFT   JOIN load_driver_contractor_credits ld ON ld.id = n.load_driver_contractor_credit_id
LEFT   JOIN load_payables                  lp ON lp.id = n.load_payable_id
LEFT   JOIN load_payments                  lm ON lm.id = n.load_payment_id
LEFT   JOIN loads                          l2 ON l2.id = lm.load_id

LEFT   JOIN payments                       p1 ON p1.id = n.payment_id
LEFT   JOIN payment_items                  pi ON pi.id = n.payment_item_id

LEFT   JOIN payments                       p2 ON p2.id = pi.bill_id
LEFT   JOIN payment_details                pd ON pd.id = pi.payment_detail_id
LEFT   JOIN statements                     st ON st.id = n.statement_id
WHERE  t.id <> n.transaction_id;  -- to affect *all* other rows.

-- I left the rest for you to incorporate as well:

IF NEW.statement_fuel_id IS NOT NULL THEN
 UPDATE transactions SET associated_truck_id  = (SELECT truck_id  FROM statement_fuel WHERE statement_fuel.id  = NEW.statement_fuel_id) WHERE id = transaction_id;
 UPDATE transactions SET associated_driver_id = (SELECT driver_id FROM statement_fuel WHERE statement_fuel.id  = NEW.statement_fuel_id) WHERE id = transaction_id;
 UPDATE transactions SET associated_check_no  = (SELECT check_no  FROM statements     WHERE statements.id      = NEW.statement_id)      WHERE id = transaction_id;
END IF;

IF NEW.work_order_id IS NOT NULL THEN
 UPDATE transactions SET associated_business_partner_id = (SELECT customer_id   FROM work_orders WHERE work_orders.id  = NEW.work_order_id) WHERE id = transaction_id;
 UPDATE transactions SET associated_invoice_no     = CAST((SELECT work_order_no FROM work_orders WHERE work_orders.id  = NEW.work_order_id) AS TEXT) WHERE id = transaction_id;
 UPDATE transactions SET associated_check_no            = (SELECT check_no      FROM work_orders WHERE work_orders.id  = NEW.work_order_id) WHERE id = transaction_id;      
END IF;

END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;


CREATE TRIGGER ins_aft
AFTER INSERT ON transactions
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE trg_transactions_ins_aft();
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I recently started working at a new place and they require me to learn postgreSQL. Unrelated to this question, but you seem like a knowledgeable fellow, would http://www.postgresql.org/docs/ be a good start for learning or is there a book that you think would be a good choice? Thank you again

Comment: @Azar_Javed: The manual is excellent. Highly recommended. For starters some book would be good, too. It has been to long since I had use for those, so I have no recommendation there.